# How to get a file name in C

Tags: c, file

I am trying to get a file name in C, at my project I will have three files, like `Randomic%08d.txt`, `Inverted%08d.txt` and `Ordered%08d.txt`, where this `%08d` represents the range I typed, if I typed range equal 3, the file name will be `Randomic00000003.txt`. I thought to get a file name just returning the file name at the functions in `generateFiles.h` but I guess that is not good to do because I will have change the return function type.
I want to get the file name because I will need to define a vector with the file data so I need to open the file.

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "generateFiles.h"

int main(void) {
  FILE *ordered, *inverted, *randomic;
  int range, choice;
  char fileName[255];

  do {
    printf("Menu\n\n");
    printf("1 - Criar arquivos \n");
    printf("2 - Ordenar usando Bubble Sort \n");
    printf("3 - Ordenar usando Insertion Sort \n");
    printf("4 - Fechar programa \n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
      case 1:
        printf("Informe o tamanho do arquivo: ");
        scanf("%d", &range);
        createOrderedFile(range, fileName, ordered);
        createInvertedFile(range, fileName, inverted);
        createRandomicFile(range, fileName, randomic);
        break;
      case 2:
        fopen("Randomic%08d.txt", "r");
        break;
    }
  } while(choice != 4);
}
```

### generateFiles.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int INDEX = 0;

void createOrderedFile(int range, char fileName[255], FILE *ordered) {
  int index;
  sprintf(fileName, "Ordered%08d.txt", range);
  ordered = fopen(fileName, "w");
  for (INDEX = 1; INDEX <= range; INDEX++) {
    fprintf(ordered, "%d\n", INDEX);
  }
  fclose(ordered);
}

void createInvertedFile(int range, char fileName[255], FILE *inverted) {
  sprintf(fileName, "Inverted%08d.txt", range);
  inverted = fopen(fileName, "w");
  for (INDEX = range; INDEX >= 1; INDEX--) {
    fprintf(inverted, "%d\n", INDEX);
  }
  fclose(inverted);
}

void createRandomicFile(int range, char fileName[255], FILE *randomic) {
  sprintf(fileName, "Randomic%08d.txt", range);
  randomic = fopen(fileName, "w");
  for (INDEX = 1; INDEX <= range; INDEX++) {
    fprintf(randomic, "%d\n", rand() % range + 1);
  }
  fclose(randomic);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. That the three calls in the `case 1:` block all write (different) names to the same place, or how to get the proper filename for the `case 2:`? Either way, your `fopen` call is discarding its return value, so the `FILE*` object(s) can't be used.

Comment: @AdrianMole it is a little MVP but at the `case 2:` I will need to get the file name but the file name could be a dynamic like `Randomic0000001.txt` or `Randomic1000000.txt`.

Comment: Hmm. You'll likely need three *separate* filenames and use the value last written to the relevant file type for whatever 'read' operation you want to do. Still not really clear.

Comment: @AdrianMole For example, in case 2, I want to get the filename of each file I'm creating in the functions, however, I want to get it dynamically, because if I put it hard coded, I can change my range, and so the file changes its name.

Comment: So, `case 2` will only *ever* be done after a `case 1` has already generated the filename(s)? If so, just use three different strings: `char fileNameO[256];`, `char fileNameI[256];` ...

Comment: @AdrianMole Good idea, but are there other way to get the file name without create other file name variables?